# Centralizers and intersections in the Gromov-boundary of the mapping class group

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, mapping-class-groups

The mapping class group of a punctured surface $\Sigma$ is weakly relatively hyperbolic (see below), hence it is well defined the Gromov-boundary with respect to the relative metric.

*First question:* let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be finite subgroups of the mapping class group $Mod(\Sigma)$ and $F=\langle F_1,F_2\rangle$ the group generated by their union. Is it true that the closure of the centralizer $\overline{C(F)}$ in the Gromov compactification of $Mod(\Sigma)$ is equal to the intersection of the closures of the centralizers of $F_1$ and $F_2$ ?

$
\overline{C(F)}\stackrel{?}{=}\overline{C(F_1)}\cap \overline{C(F_2)}
$

Remark: the answer is affirmative if $F$ is finite because the boundary of the centralizer of a finite group in the Gromov compactification can be identified with the set of minimal geodesic laminations fixed by that group.

Actually, what I am interested in is somewhat simpler. I would like to know if it is true that when the group $F$ is not finite the set of geodesic laminations fixed by $F$ is small. For example the following fact would be sufficient for my purpose:

*Second question:* let $F_1$ be a finite group of the mapping class group and $F_2=gF_1g^{-1}$ a conjugate of $F_1$. Is it true that if the group generated by their unioin $F=\langle F_1,F_2\rangle$ is infinite then it contains a pseudo-Anosov element?

EDIT: by weakly relatively hyperbolic I mean that there exist a finite set $S$ generating $Mod(\Sigma)$ and some subgroups $H_1,\ldots,H_n<Mod(\Sigma)$ such that $Mod(\Sigma)$ is $\delta$-hyperbolic with respect to the word metric with characters in $S\cup H_1\cup\cdots\cup H_n$. Masur and Minsky showed that there exists a choice for the $H_i$'s such that $Mod(\Sigma)$ with the relative metric is quasi-isometric to the curve complex, and the latter is hyperbolic. ($H_i$ is defined as $Fix(a_i)$ where the $a_i$'s are some representatives of the orbits of the action of $Mod(\Sigma)$ on the set of isotopy classes of essential curves of $\Sigma$.) I am referring to the metric relative to these subgroups.

Comment: Could you precise what do you mean by "weakly hyperbolic" ? There are many different definitions.

Comment: could you let me know the reference for the remark about the boundary of centralizer?

Comment: I found this fact in section 2 of this article: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604433